# Какой приоритет у селектора по атрибуту?

Tags: css

- Приоритет селектор тега - 1 условная единица.
- Приоритет селектор класса - 10 условных единиц.

Сколько единиц дает селектор атрибута?

Comment: о чем хоть речь-то ?

Answer (score 4):

Обратимся к [спецификации](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#specificity)

> Специфичность селектора определяется по следующим правилам
>
> 1. Количество ID селекторов в селекторе (= a)
> 2. Количество селекторов класса, селекторов по атрибуту, селекторов псевдо-классов (= b)
> 3. Количество селекторов по типу (имя тега) и селекторов псевдо-элементов (= c)
> 4. Универсальный селектор игнорируется
>
> > **Важно:**  Селекторы внутри `:not` учитываются как обычно, однако сам `:not` не считается как псевдо-класс.
>
> Объединение трех чисел a-b-c дает специфичность.
>
> ```
> *               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
> LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
> UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
> UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
> H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
> UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
> LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
> #x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
> #s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
> ```

Comment: Ого, можно в двух словах, зачем это нужно?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, зачем нужно что? :-) Это правила, по которым браузер должен определять какой стиль в итоге нужно применить к элементу

Comment: Вот эта информация в ответе, т.е. где это применяется на практике, а то вовсе впервые это вижу)

Comment: #s12:not(FOO) --> почему специфичность равна 101? Ведь :not - псевдо-класс, значит его специфичность равна 10

Comment: @brian, а какой результат ты ожидал? (обновил ответ)

Comment: #s12:not(FOO) --> 110:     #s12 --> 100 (селектор по ID), :not --> 10 (псевдо-класс отрицания)

Comment: @brian, добавил уточнение в ответ

Comment: @Grundy Помогите ТС с формулировкой вопроса. В текущем виде действительно не совсем понятно о чём речь. К тому же, правка бы поставила топик в очередь на переоткрытие, что бы ускорило процесс.