# Какой смысл в записи span#id?

Tags: css

Какой смысл в записи span#id?
Eсть ли какое-то отличие от #id?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем примере, скорее всего, такое правило составлено для того, чтобы наверняка "перебить" стили заданные `span`-у где-то ещё. Т.к. `#` (id) имеет большую специфичность ("вес"), то он "перекроет" такие селекторы, как: `span`, `span[id=id]` и `span.class`.

Answer (score 2):

Запись в стиле `span#id` даёт приоритет над записью вида `#id` из-за спецификации, подробнее о ней в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1101043/272305).

```css
#a {
  color: red;
}

p#a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="a">Синий текст</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Де-факто ничего не мешает иметь несколько различных элементов с одинаковым `id` (хотя это и идет вразрез со спецификацией). Такая запись позволяет сузить скоуп локатора, чтобы избавиться от возможной неоднозначности.